# Simple jquery ajax post php not working

Tags: php, jquery

Hi iam learning jquery with php. I created very small php and jquery code to getting value but it's not working. I check console but not giving any information i have referred jquery api documentation same process i followed but no use. How can i solve this.

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#submit").click(function(){
           var term= $("#sterm").val();          
           $.post('oopsdata.php', {nwterm: term}, function(data){
               ("#container").html(data);
           });
       });
   });
   </script>

    <body>
     <form class="" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="" value="" id="sterm">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Search term" id="submit">
     </form>
     <div id="container">olddata</div>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
   $newterm = $_POST['nwterm'];
   if($newterm == 'bio'){
       echo "Request received This is the new data"
   } else {
       echo "no data received;"
   }
?>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: dont make the submit button as type submit or make prevent default

Comment: First: `("#container").html(data);` the `$` is missing here in front of the parenthesis. Second: when submitting a form the site usually reloads so you will not see the output from your ajax call. Use `event.preventDefault` or don't use a submit button

Comment: yes i use jquery library file in my project

Comment: Why skip naming your inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- You need to prevent your form from being submitted in the first place. Use jQuery's [`.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)
- Missing `$` before `("#container").html(data);`

Based on the above two points, your jQuery code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        var term= $("#sterm").val();          
        $.post('oopsdata.php', {nwterm: term}, function(data){
            $("#container").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

- There are two syntax errors in your PHP code. Missing `;` in both your `echo` statements.

So based on the above point, your PHP code should be like this:

```
<?php
    $newterm = $_POST['nwterm'];
    if($newterm == 'bio'){
        echo "Request recieved This is the new data";
    }else{
        echo "no data recieved";
    }
?>
```